# Is there a simple example for validation of method parameters with Seam Validation?

Tags: seam, hibernate-validator

I'm stuck...
I know https://github.com/gunnarmorling/methodvalidation-integration/tree/master/methodvalidation-cdi, which works fine, and I know that there's Seam Validation that should help me validate my method parameters within Hibernate Validator 4.2.0

I refactored the example above to use Seam Validation:

- Replaced `AutoValidating` and `ValidationInterceptor` with Seam Validation's classes
- Changed `beans.xml` to use `org.jboss.seam.validation.ValidationInterceptor`
- Changed `CdiMethodValidationTest` to use Seam Validation's `ValidationInterceptor`
- Added `seam-validation-api` and `seam-validation` 3.1.0.Final to the Maven POM
- Changed `arquillian-weld-se-embedded-1` to `arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1` in the POM

All I get is

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.api.Bootstrap.parse(Ljava/lang/Iterable;)Lorg/jboss/weld/bootstrap/spi/BeansXml;
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.weld.ee.embedded_1_1.mock.TestContainer.<init>(TestContainer.java:215)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.weld.ee.embedded_1_1.WeldEEMockContainer.deploy(WeldEEMockContainer.java:76)
at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.handler.ContainerDeployer.callback(ContainerDeployer.java:62)
at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.handler.ContainerDeployer.callback(ContainerDeployer.java:50)
at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.event.MapEventManager.fire(MapEventManager.java:63)
at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.context.AbstractEventContext.fire(AbstractEventContext.java:115)
at org.jboss.arquillian.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeClass(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:96)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:162)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3$1.evaluate(Arquillian.java:186)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$MultiStatementExecutor.execute(Arquillian.java:297)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:182)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:127)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of Weld do you have on your class path? Your Arquillian container expects Weld 1.1, have you maybe still an older version? That said, I highly recommend to consider using Bean Validation 1.1 / Hibernate Validator 5, which also provides an integration with CDI. Seam Validation is not actively maintained anymore.

Comment: Hi Gunnar! Thanks for your comment, I changed the POM to use Weld 1.1.13.Final, Seam 3.1.0.Final, Arquillian 1.0.3.Final and Arquillian Weld 1.0.0.CR3. Now I get java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
 at org.slf4j.cal10n.LocLogger.info(LocLogger.java:125)
 at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.<clinit>(WeldBootstrap.java:206)
 at org.jboss.arquillian.container.weld.ee.embedded_1_1.mock.TestContainer.<init>(TestContainer.java:211)
...

Comment: @Gunnar Bean Validation 1.1 certainly looks good. However, can I use it within a JEE 6 container (JBoss EAP 6)?

Comment: Regarding the AbstractMethodError, it seems like API and implementation version of slf4j don't match. You need to make sure both are used in the same version. Regarding using BV 1.1 / HV 5 on EAP 6, it should be possible, but requires some manual steps. Basically you'd have to replace the HV module of the application server with a hand-made one for HV 5.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information. I don't think it's worth the trouble, I'll wait for Bean Validation 1.1 and look into integrating it in EAP 6.